# How to display object into different tabs

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner with javascript and I have a problem displaying 'renderMovieCard(theMovie)' into the specific tab. Although I can display the card in the first tab,by calling the function createmovie(). But I'm not sure how to fetch the Object from the array and display it into specific Tab. I will appreciate any help or hint.

My attempt to fetch the object and display it at:
// Generate All Movies VIEW

```js
// Movies Stored in array
movies = [];

// Constructor Object
function Movie(id, name, type, description, image, isWatched, favorite){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.description = description;
    this.image = image;
    this.isWatched = isWatched;
    this.favorite = favorite;
}
// Generate Random id for the movie
function generateId(){
    let max = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i ++){
        if(movies[i].id > max){
            max = movies[i].id;
        }
    }
    return max + 1;
}

// Add Movie Object
function createmovie(){
    let movieName = document.getElementById('movieName').value;
    let movieType = document.getElementById('movieType').value;
    let movieDescription = document.getElementById('movieDescription').value;
    let movieCoverImg = document.getElementById('movieCoverImg').value;
    let movieisWatched = document.getElementById('isWatched').checked;
    let movieFavorite = document.getElementById('favourite').checked;

    let theMovie = new Movie(generateId(),movieName, movieType, movieDescription, movieCoverImg, movieisWatched, movieFavorite);
    movies.push(theMovie);
    clearFormInputs();
    notify();
    
}

// GENERATE VIEW //
function renderMovieCard(theMovie){
    
    let masterParent = document.getElementById('containerAll');

    let movieParentBox = document.createElement('movieBox');
    movieParentBox.id = 'movieBox';
    
    let movieImage = document.createElement('img');
    movieImage.id = 'movieBoxImage';
    movieImage.src = theMovie.image;

    let movieDetails = document.createElement('div');
    movieDetails.className = 'movieDetails';

    let movieBoxName = document.createElement('h4');
    movieBoxName.id = 'movieBoxName';
    movieBoxName.innerText = theMovie.name;

    let movieBoxType = document.createElement('p');
    movieBoxType.id = 'movieBoxType';
    movieBoxType.className = 'py';
    movieBoxType.innerText = theMovie.type;

    let movieBoxDescription = document.createElement('p');
    movieBoxDescription.id = 'movieBoxDescription';
    movieBoxDescription.className = 'py';
    movieBoxDescription.innerText = theMovie.description;

    let chkFavSpace = document.createElement('div');
    chkFavSpace.className = 'flx', 'py', 'chkFavSpace';

    let checkI = document.createElement('i');;
    checkI.className = 'fas fa-check-circle chk fa-2x';

    let checkH = document.createElement('i');
    checkH.className = 'fas fa-heart fav fa-2x'


    movieParentBox.appendChild(movieImage);
    movieDetails.appendChild(movieBoxName);
    movieDetails.appendChild(movieBoxType);
    movieDetails.appendChild(movieBoxDescription);
    movieDetails.appendChild(chkFavSpace);
    chkFavSpace.appendChild(checkI);
    chkFavSpace.appendChild(checkH);
    movieParentBox.appendChild(movieDetails);
    masterParent.appendChild(movieParentBox);
}

// Generate All Movies VIEW
function AllMovies(movies){
    let AllMovies = document.getElementById('containerAll');
    for(let i = 0; i < movies.length; i ++){
        view = renderMovieCard(movies[i]);
        AllMovies.appendChild(view);
    }
    
}

// Generate Movies - Watched


// Generate Movies - Watchlist


// Generate Movies - Favorites

// Clear Form 
function clearFormInputs(){
    movieName = document.getElementById('movieName').value = '';
    movieType = document.getElementById('movieType').value = 'Other';
    movieDescription = document.getElementById('movieDescription').value = '';
    movieCoverImg = document.getElementById('movieCoverImg').value = '';
    movieisWatched = document.getElementById('isWatched').checked = false;
    movieFavorite = document.getElementById('favourite').checked = false;
}

// Add Movie Btn - ADD MOVIE INTO LIST
let btnAddMovie = document.getElementById('btnaddMovie');
btnAddMovie.addEventListener('click', function(){
    createmovie();
    let form = document.getElementById('myModal');
    form.style.display = 'none';
})

// Close Btn - ADD MOVIE FORM
let btnCancel = document.getElementById('btnCancel');
btnCancel.addEventListener('click', function(){
    modal.style.display = "none";
});
// Close Btn - Notification Form
let btnClose= document.getElementById('spanClose');
btnClose.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('notificationAddMovie').style.display = 'none';
});

// Notification - Added movie
function notify(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('notificationAddMovie').style.display = 'block'
    }, 500);
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('notificationAddMovie').style.display = 'none'
    }, 4000);
}

// tabs
function openMovie(evt, movieName) {
  let i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(movieName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += "active";
}
// modalbox
// Get the modal
let modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
// Get the button that opens the modal
let btn = document.getElementById("showModal");
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
:root{
    --color-color:#0b032d;
    --color2-color:#621940;
    --color3-color:#843b62;
    --color4-color:#50082e;
}
*{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
/* Header */
#headerContainer{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:space-around;
    align-items:center;
    height:120px;
    background-color:var(--color2-color);
    color:#fff;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 1.95px 1.95px 2.6px;
}
#logo{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    align-items: center;  
}
#logo h1{
    margin-left:10px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
.btnAdd{
    padding:0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem;
    border:0;
    background-color:var(--color3-color);
    border-radius:3px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color:#FFF;
}
.btnAdd:hover{
    background-color:var(--color4-color); 
}
/* Content */
#container{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:60%;
    padding-top:30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
/* Tab containers */
#containerAll{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}
#Watched{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}
#Watchlist{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}
#Favourites{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}


/* Modal Box Extra Info*/
#formAddMovie{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flx{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
.justFlx{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.clmn{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
#btnaddMovie{
    width:120px;
    padding:0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem;
    margin-right:20px;
    border:none;
    border-radius:3px;
    background-color:var(--color4-color);
    color:#FFF;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:0.5s;
}
#btnCancel{
    width:120px;
    padding:0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem;
    margin-right:20px;
    border:none;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #666;
    color:#333;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:0.5s;
}
#btnaddMovie:hover{
    background-color:var(--color2-color);
}

input, select, textarea{
    border:0px;
    border-radius:3px;
    padding:0.5rem 0.3rem 0.5rem 0.3rem;
    color:#666;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.py{
    padding-top:1rem;
    padding-bottom:1rem;
}
textarea{
    resize:none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
/* Input fields shadow red -removed*/
input:required {
    box-shadow: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.2) 0px 2px 2px 0px;
}
select:required {
    box-shadow: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.2) 0px 2px 2px 0px;
}
textarea:required {
    box-shadow: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.2) 0px 2px 2px 0px;
}


/* Notification */
#notificationAddMovie{
    display: none;
    position:fixed;
    height:30px;
    padding:0.7rem 1.2rem 0.7rem 1.2rem;
    bottom:10px;
    left:10px;
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
    color:#666;
    font-family: helvetica;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
#notificationAddMovie p{
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
}
#notificationAddMovie span{
    background-color: #999;
    color:#fff;
    padding:0px 4px 1px 4px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#spanClose:hover{
    background-color:#333;
}
.green{
    color:rgb(24, 78, 24);
    background-color:#fff;
}


/* movieBox */

#movieBox{
    margin:0.3rem;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#movieBox img{
    border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom:4px solid var(--color3-color);
    width:200px;
}
.movieDetails{
  
    padding:0.5rem;
}
.chkFavSpace{
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.chk, .fav{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.chk{
    color:rgb(24, 78, 24);
}
.fav{
    color:rgb(150, 41, 41);
}
.py{
    padding:0.3rem 0rem 0.3rem 0rem;
}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #621940;
  color:#fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  color:#fff;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #843b62;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #50082e;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 0.3px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-top: none;
}
#All, #Watched, #Watchlist, #Favourites h3{
  color:#666;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color:#666;
    border-radius:3px;
    
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 30%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:0.3s;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
label{
    padding:1rem 0rem 0.2rem 0rem;
}
#watched, #favourite{
    margin-top:12px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href = './css/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href = './css/tabs.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href = './css/modalBox.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f1db609589.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header id = 'headerContainer'>
        <div id = 'logo'>
            <i class="fas fa-video fa-2x"></i>
            <h1>Muvico</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="showModal">
            <button id = 'showModal' class = 'btnAdd'><i class="fa fa-film"></i>&nbsp;Add Movie</button>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <!-- Tabs -->
            <div class = 'tab'>
                <button class = 'tablinks' onclick = "openMovie(event, 'All')"><i class="fas fa-photo-video"></i>&nbsp;All</button>
                <button class = 'tablinks' onclick = "openMovie(event, 'Watched')"><i class="fas fa-video-slash"></i>&nbsp;Watched</button>
                <button class = 'tablinks' onclick = "openMovie(event, 'Watchlist')"><i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i>&nbsp;Watchlist</button>
                <button class = 'tablinks' onclick = "openMovie(event, 'Favourites')"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i>&nbsp;Favourites</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Content for Tabs-->
            <div id="All" class = 'tabcontent'>
                <h3>All Movies</h3>
                <div id="containerAll">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Watched" class = 'tabcontent'>
                <h3>Watched Movies</h3>
                <div id="containerWatched">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Watchlist" class = 'tabcontent'>
                <h3>Watchlist</h3>
                <div id="containerWatchlist">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Favourites" class = 'tabcontent'>
                <h3>Favourite</h3>
                <div id="containerFavorite">

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Modal Box -->
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <div id="formAddMovie">
                <label for = 'movieName'>Name</label>
                <input type = 'text' id = 'movieName' placeholder = 'movie name...' name = 'movieName' required>
                <label for = 'movieType'>Type</label>
                <select name = 'movieType' id = 'movieType' required>
                    <option value = 'other'>Other</option>
                    <option value = 'horror'>Horror</option>
                    <option value = 'comedy'>Comedy</option>
                    <option value = 'romance'>Romance</option>
                    <option value = 'scifi'>Sci-FI</option>
                    <option value = 'action'>Action</option>
                    <option value = 'adventure'>Adventure</option>
                    <option value = 'drama'>Drama</option>
                    <option value = 'documentary'>Documentary</option>
                </select>
                <label for = 'movieDescription'>Description</label>
                <textarea id = 'movieDescription' name = 'movieDescription' rows = 5 cols = 5 placeholder = 'movie description..' required></textarea>
                <label for = 'movieCoverImg'>Cover image URL</label>
                <input id = 'movieCoverImg' name = 'movieCoverImg' placeholder = 'movie cover image' required>
                <div class="justFlx">
                    <input type = 'checkbox' id = 'isWatched' name = 'isWatched' value = 0 >
                    <label for = 'isWatched'>&nbsp;Watched</label>
                    <input type = 'checkbox' id = 'favourite' name = 'favourite' value = 0>
                    <label for = 'favourite'>&nbsp;Favorite</label>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="flx py">
                    <button id = 'btnaddMovie'>Add Movie</button>
                    <button id = 'btnCancel'>Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Movie Add Box-->
    <div id = 'notificationAddMovie'>
        <p><i class="fas fa-check-circle green"></i> Successfully added&nbsp;<span id = 'spanClose'>x</span></p>
    </div>
    
    <script src = './js/app.js'></script>
    <script src = './js/tabs.js'></script>
    <script src = './js/modalBox.js'></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possibly "each" tab needs its own dom and thus its own resources.

Answer (score 0):

Each tab have its own DOM tree and don't share or access DOM directly with one another. Here you can do one thing, store this movie object into localstorage as localstorage is shared across tabs of samd domain. When you get movie object into second tab from localstorage then create a new DOM inside second tab using that movie object.

Comment: This solution requires more work than is simply instantiating the object